# Adding new element to array with useState React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to add a couple of inputs from multi-select to array.
Here is my code. Problem is that in the result previous element in the array is set undefined
I have tried to do it in different ways, but it doesn't work.

```
const SignUp = ({signUp, projectsList}) => {


const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    role: '',
    username: '',
    projects: [],
});

const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    console.log("event", event);
    if (name === "projects") {
        return setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: event.map((v) => v.value),
        });

    } else {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    }
};
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signUp(formData);
    history.push('/');
};
return {
 <Select
        name="projects"
        placeholder="Select Project"
        value={formData.projects}
        options={projectsList.map((proj) => {
            return {
                label: proj.name,
                value: proj.id
            }
        })}
        key={key + Math.random() + 11 * 1000}
        onChange={handleChange('projects')}
        isMulti={true}
        isClearable={true}
 />
}
```

The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

First things first, there is no need to have key={key + Math.random() + 11 * 1000}. Key prop should be applied to parent divisions preferably getting unique ids from back-end.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select"

const options = [
  {
    label: "p1",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "p2",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "p3",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "p4",
    value: 4
  }
]

function App() {

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

  const handleChange = (name, values) => {
    if (name === "projects") {
      const captured = values.map((ele) => {
        return ele.value
      })
      setProjects(captured)
    } else {
      // logic for other than name = projects
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        isMulti={true}
        options={options}
        onChange={(element) => handleChange("projects", element)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Screenshot: [image: projects console]

Comment: Firstly, (+1) for the answer. Couple of points: A) Please consider if `captured` may be removed and instead we may directly do the update like so: `if (name === 'projects') setProjects(values.map(({value}) => value);`. B) There is one observation, if I may share: the OP  seems to use `setFormData` with the intention to consolidate all of the form's inputs into one structure, and may be potentially use the same `handleChange` method for multiple inputs.

Comment: (A) I kept 'captured' because the author of the question had the if block so I thought that might be important ? Nevertheless, you are right, 'captured' can be removed if wanted. Also, setProjects(values.map(ele => ele.value)) can also work. No problem in that. (B) Well handleChange can be used for multiple inputs. It all depends on the structure.